# I will not in any case kick the ball or I will in any case not kick the ball

Tags: sentence-structure, word-order, negation

1. > I will not in any case kick the ball.
2. > I will in any case not kick the ball.
3. > I in any case will not kick the ball.
4. > I will not kick in any case the ball.

I think only the fourth one is wrong, and all of the others seem fine to me. Please tell me if there are any wrong ones (and why), because after looking at them for so long, I just lost my sense of English. Also, please tell me if some of them have to be used with commas like below:

> I, in any case, will not kick the ball.

Comment: 4 is definitely wrong.  You might need commas for 1 and/or 3.  I have a bad habit of overusing them.

Comment: "I won't kick the ball, no matter what." or "I won't kick the ball, no matter what happens." or "In any case, I won't kick the ball." sound more natural to my (American) ear.  The phrase "kick the ball" is informal, so the contraction "won't" has a consistent level of (in)formality.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that 1) and 3) are correct, though I think they work better with commas:

> 1) I will not, in any case, kick the ball.
>
> 3) I, in any case, will not kick the ball.

2) could be correct, though it sounds a bit "off" to me. I would stay away from 4) - it sounds rather jumbled and a bit over the place.